# For me, the fun begins at 9:35 UTC

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge

> so there I was, trying to find a new puzzle idea.
>
> Obviously it should be something good. For this amazing community of puzzlers,
>   nothing less than the best will do. So come on, Rubio (I tell myself), why don't you
>   quit spending all your time on PSE doing all that "moderation" stuff and ... well ...
>   just post a puzzle already!  Ah, here's an idea: how about something that requires a little
>   knowledge. Of, say, music videos. This Billboard Top 10 list looks useful... Yes! Michael
>   Jackson!  I think I can work with this. So what *exactly* should I do... think... think....
>
> That's it!
>   Make a puzzle using a YouTube video itself! Can't be too easy or they'll be disappointed,
>   and can't be too hard or they'll be grumpy.  I think if I tell them exactly which YT video,
>   AND I give them some specific things to look for it, this might just work!

***Things to look for:***

[image: Yeah ... you were scared]   
[image: It's close to]   
[image: You hear the door]

[image: Save you from the terror]   
[image: ...Hell]   
[image: But terror]

[image: Midnight]   
[image: Down]   
[image: [walking]]

[image: You]   
[image: ...Dial]   
[image: [headstones]]

[image: You hear a creature]   
[image: Out to get]   
[image: [graveyard]]

---

**What is this puzzle saying?**

**—HINTS—**

*helpfulness level 0:*

> Order is important.

*helpfulness level 1:*

> The things to look for are *not* given in the correct order.

*helpfulness level 2:*

> [kamenf's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56518) has the correct time indices for each thing to look for, but as the previous hint says, those things to look for are *not* given in the correct order. What difference does that make?

Comment: Don't have time to explore the idea, but perhaps we need to find the video, freeze at each moment and the relating time will tell us something... maybe steganography...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It says

> HAPPY HALLOWEEN

as we can see by

> putting the frames in time order, counting the seconds between them, and using A1Z26.

Note that

> the actual hard work was done by kamenf, in figuring out those times; if you like this answer, go and upvote the other one.

Answer (score 10):

Partial:

> Times of the frames:
>
>  Yeah ... you were scared - 4:35  
>  It's close to - 4:43
>  You hear the door - 5:16
>
>  Save you from the terror - 6:14
>  ...Hell - 6:57
>  But terror - 5:00
>
>  Midnight - 4:44
>  Down - 6:52
>  [walking] - 7:16
>
>  You - 5:50
>  ...Dial - 6:02
>  [headstones] - 7:02
>
>  You hear a creature 5:41
>  Out to get - 5:49
>  [graveyard] - 6:29
>
>  At 9:35 there is a "look back"... if this could mean something.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first frame is from 4:35, and 4:35 is equivalent to 9:35UTC where @Rubio lives.

Comment: @feelinferrety perhaps a good observation but does it mean additional tags which help users in understanding such 'non-puzzling factors are need to be added?!